# Unable to fetch api after changing date format

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I am fetching a railways api, however the api requires date to be in dd-mm-yyyy format so I converted it from mm-dd-yyyy format to dd-mm-yyyy, now on clicking submit button no train data is fetched.

Here is the code.

```
  searchTrain(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let journeyDate = this.dateFormatter(this.state.date)
    this.setState({ date: journeyDate }, () => console.log(this.state.date))
    this.fetchTrainList();
    //this.setState({ to: '', from: '', date: '' })
  }

  fetchTrainList() {
  fetch(`https://api.railwayapi.com/v2/between/source/${this.state.from}/dest/${this.state.to}/date/${this.state.date}/apikey/sch2lk34nw/`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({ trainList: data }
          , () => console.log(this.state.trainList)
        )
      })
  }

  onChangeTrain(e) {
    this.setState(
      { [e.target.id]: e.target.value }
         , () => console.log(this.state)
    );
  }

  dateFormatter(date) {
    const options = { year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit' };
    return new Date(date).toLocaleDateString('en-IN', options).split('/').join('-');
  }
```

Comment: instal redux-logger first to make sure actions are being dispatched as expected, then go to network tab in browsers developer tools to check the request and response from the api to figure out if the api is being called properly and what data is it returning.

Comment: I am not using redux. I am just checking in console

Comment: I like @VaibhavVishal's idea - also, `this.setState` is asynchronous, so you should call `this.fetchTrainList()` inside the callback -> a.k.a. where you do `console.log(this.state.date)`

Comment: this.setState({ date: journeyDate }, () => this.fetchTrainList())  gives me Error: Object too large to inspect. Open your browser console to view.

Comment: this.setState({ date: journeyDate }, () => this.fetchTrainList()) worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.setState` is asynchronous, so you should call `this.fetchTrainList()` inside the `this.setState` callback, like this:

```
this.setState({
    date: journeyDate,
}, () => {
    this.fetchTrainList()
});
```

Or you can in-line it as you have done:

```
this.setState({ date: journeyDate }, () => this.fetchTrainList());
```

Answer (score 0):

What does your network log say? I tried to use their curl from https://railwayapi.com/api/#train-route but got a 500 response.

Might not be an issue on your end

Comment: I got the error solved. It was because of async this.setState